# What is the maximum value of the integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, contest-math, problem-solving

Suppose $a<b$. The maximum value of the integral
$$\int_{a}^{b}(\frac{3}{4}-x-x^{2})dx$$ over all possible values of $a$ and $b$.

**note-** We can see that the function inside the integral is a decreasing function so what interval do we have to look at to get the answer. I thought the interval to be should be of such length such that $a-b$ becomes minimum so that the integral can be maximised but no definite answer comes to mind. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: This isn't really a calculus problem

Comment: Calculate the maximal interval $[a,b]$ on which your integrand $1-(x+1/2)^2$ is $\ge0.$

Comment: The integrand is polynomial, that is why you can determine its explicit antiderivative easily. Then, this definite integral will be a mere function of $a$ and $b$, which can be optimized as any bivariate function.

Comment: The integrand is **increasing** till $x=-1/2$ then decreasing...

Comment: Who has spoken about *bivariate* function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{a}^{b}(\frac{3}{4}-x-x^{2})dx$$

$$f(x)=\frac{3}{4}-x-x^{2}=\frac{1}{4}(-4x^2-4x+3)=\frac{-1}{4}\left(2x-1\right)\left(2x+3\right)$$

[image]

The maximum area under this integral would be $$I=\int_{\frac{-3}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{3}{4}-x-x^{2})dx=\frac{3x}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}|_{\frac{-3}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\approx0.667$$